# Oracle user PID, ORA-00600: internal error

Tags: oracle, pid

I need a function which returns the user PID. Following [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2133315?tstart=0) I wrote the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SPID
RETURN SMALLINT
AS
RES SMALLINT := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT PID INTO RES FROM V$PROCESS WHERE ADDR=(SELECT PADDR FROM V$SESSION WHERE SID=(SELECT SID FROM V$SESSION WHERE AUDSID=SPID()));
RETURN RES;
END;
```

However, when I try to do a

```
SELECT SPID() FROM DUAL;
```

I get an ORA-00600 error:

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [KPDB-MAX_SWITCH], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 
ORA-06512: at "RNDSUITE.SPID", line 6
...
```

Any remedy is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have pid with this:

```
select 
   pid,spid 
from 
   v$process 
where 
   ADDR=(select paddr from v$session where AUDSID=sys_context('USERENV', 'sessionid'));
```